# Increase Container size

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I need to increase the height of my container in Stack for more text space in bottom like this:

[image]

My code:

```
GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: ScrollPhysics(),
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    children: List.generate(10, (index) {
        return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Stack(
                children: < Widget > [
                    Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.05), offset: Offset(0, 3), blurRadius: 7),
                            ],
                        ),
                        child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                            child: Text(
                                categoryName[index % categoryName.length],
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: const Color(0xFF71768D),
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                ),
                            ),
                        )
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                        top: 0,
                        left: 0.0,
                        right: 0.0,
                        child: MaterialButton(
                            onPressed: null,
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                            disabledColor: colorList[index % colorList.length],
                            child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                iconList[index % iconList.length],
                                width: 40,
                                height: 40,
                            ),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                            shape: CircleBorder(),
                        )
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                        top: 0,
                        left: 0.0,
                        right: 0.0,
                        child: MaterialButton(
                            onPressed: null,
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                            disabledColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
                            child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                iconList[index % iconList.length],
                                width: 40,
                                height: 40,
                            ),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                            shape: CircleBorder(),
                        )
                    )
                ]
            )
        );
    })
),
```

The container in which the text is located for some reason does not stretch more than the specified value in my grid. In the picture that i attached this is the maximum height, on a real phone this block is even smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By changing `childAspectRatio` 0 to 1 you can change hight of item

```
GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: ScrollPhysics(),
    childAspectRatio: 0.6
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    children: List.generate(10, (index) {
        return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Stack(
                children: < Widget > [
                    Container(
            child: Text('Sample')
        );
    })
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try with this parameters that allows you to control the spacing between the items: **crossAxisSpacing:** and **mainAxisSpacing:**

```dart
GridView.count(
          crossAxisSpacing: 2,
          mainAxisSpacing: 6,
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 250),
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: ScrollPhysics(),
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          children: List.generate(10, (index) { ...
```